# C# SqlTransaction.Commit does not throw exception

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a several SQL commands running in transaction. I use SqlBulkCopy and SqlCommand classes to perform changes in database. At first I fill one table with raw data (using SqlBulkCopy) and then I call stored procedure which performs some kind of synchronization (insert, delete, update data in other tables according raw data).

The problem is, that when I call such operation in transaction and stored procedure fails (e.g. foreign key voilation, etc.) it does not throw exception and I do not know that any error occured.

Here is the code snippet (surrounded by try/catch):

```
    SqlBulkCopy sqlUserGroupBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, transaction);
    sqlUserGroupBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = USERGROUP_SOURCE_DATA_TABLE;

    foreach (DataColumn column in UserGroupDataTable.Columns)
      sqlUserGroupBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName));

    sqlUserGroupBulkCopy.WriteToServer(UserGroupDataTable);

    SqlCommand synchronizeCommand = new SqlCommand();
    synchronizeCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    synchronizeCommand.CommandText = SYNCHRONIZATION_SP;
    synchronizeCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("SourceName", "XXX");
    synchronizeCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Local", true);
    synchronizeCommand.Connection = connection;
    synchronizeCommand.Transaction = transaction;
    synchronizeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    transaction.Commit();
```

Thanks for answers,
  Mirek

ps: My code runs under .NET 3.5 in the IIS 7.x container.

Comment: Just a few points - first, shouldn't you have `@SourceName` as the parameter name instead of `SourceName` for example? Second, doesn't the `ExecuteNonQuery` throw the exception? That's where the FK violation or whatever happens, not during the transaction commit (at least using the default transaction settings). I'd only expect other issues, like crashed server etc. to throw an exception when commiting a transaction. What is your transaction isolation level?

Comment: A transaction commit shouldn't fail when something inside that transaction failed (you might have fixed the problem and want to commit anyway).

Comment: Post the code of the synchronization SP. The problem is likely there, not your C# code. Also, post the definition of the tables and relations involved.

Comment: OK, it is not possible to post table relations and sync SP code, because it is thousands of lines of code and tens of tables. However, when I run commands out of transaction FK voilation is thrown. Even when I run SP using Linq2SQL the exception is thrown.

Comment: BTW: '@' character is not neccessary...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,
  I've rebuilt project, restarted IIS and MS SQL Server and it started work normaly. I am quite unhappy and worried about such problem in production.

Mirek